# check in c# if an instance is a type of a class which has a generic in parameter

Tags: c#, types

I have a class called "MyClass" where T is a generic which can takes any class values between theses class ("Boy","Girl") :

```
public class MyClass<T>

public class Boy

public class Girl
```

I would like to know how to check if an object is from type MyClass.

For example, if I compare an object of type MyClass with MyClass, it should returns me true. What I have done
till now returns me false so the comparison is not good :

```
var myObject=new MyClass<Boy>();
bool test = myObject.GetType() == typeof(MyClass<>);//test variable should be true but it's false
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var myObject = new MyClass<Boy>();
bool test = myObject.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyClass<>);
```